# How to resolve HTTP Status-Code=409 conflict error in vugen replay?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

**Dear Team,**

Can I have any work around to resolve the said issue?
Getting

> HTTP Status-Code=409 conflict error

during script replay.

- I have tried all the run time settings.
- Correlated all the dynamic values.
- Played with all recording modes.

Kindly share your valuable suggestions/ideas/workarounds to fix the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Yasir.**

Answer (score 0):

Checking for expected results on each step?

Branching test execution when the expected result does not appear as expected?

Comment: Yes James..Checked results on each step and checked the expected results in application, but the expected one doesn't matched with actual result because of the said conflict error.

Comment: Then you branch, exit and restart the next iteration.  If this is a universal item across all datasets then you have unhandled dynamic data in your test script.  Record twice with the same user ID and user data set to show items related to session and state which may be unhandled.  Record a third time with a different user ID to compare and pull out account specific dynamic data.  Then a fourth time with changed data to pull out user data specific business correlations.